# Python,Kivy - How to debug TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument?

Tags: python, kivy, typeerror, dao, method-resolution-order

I have implemented DAO using Kivy's `EventDispatcher` class and mongodb

My code is structured like so:

```
class Meta(type):

    # meta deffinition

    @property
    def objects():
        #returns a db connection instance, for queries


class Model(EventDispatcher, metaclass=Meta)

    # model deffinition

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) # this is the line that causes my problem
```

And I have many models deffined with this structure:

```
class FooModel(Model):

    # foo definition


class BarModel(Model):

    # bar deffinition


class PsyModel(FooModel):

    # psy deffinition


class XPTOModel(BarModel):

    # psy deffinition

...
```

model deffinitions only add attributes, getters and setters

Isolated, model instatiation works just fine and all expected behavior is OK

But I am getting the following error in a specific part deep within my stack trace when trying to instantiate a model:

```
   File "/path/to/project/models.py", line 83, in __init__
     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 243, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
 TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

All models in my code are instantiated with the same method call, but this error is only present in a specific cenario and I am having a hard time tracing the problem.
I have inspected with debugging tools, the object, its type and the MRO, but they follow the same, desired, structure.

MRO:

```
(<class 'models.PsyModel'>, <class 'models.FooModel'>, <class 'models.Model'>, <class 'kivy._event.EventDispatcher'>, <class 'kivy._event.ObjectWithUid'>, <class 'object'>)
(<class 'models.XPTOModel'>, <class 'models.BarModel'>, <class 'models.Model'>, <class 'kivy._event.EventDispatcher'>, <class 'kivy._event.ObjectWithUid'>, <class 'object'>)
```

So I wonder what may cause this? and what to do to further understand what might be going on?

Comment: Does this happen if oyu don't do the metaclass thing?

Comment: I don't know. I'd have to refactor a lot of code to test that.. most of my DAO implementation hangs on that. But like I said, even with that there, on many other instances, the code is working just fine.. I am more interested in general runtime causes for this error

Comment: As I imagined it was the dumbest possible situation where I was indeed passing more arguments to __init__. I'll explain on my answer

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: It turns out I was indeed passing more arguments down the MRO until it reached `object.__init__`, because my kwargs had arguments that didn't match any kivy properties in the MRO classes.

So.. when instantiating Kivy's widgets, or any `EventDispatcher` subclass, with kwargs, like the following:

```
class MyClass(EventDispatcher):

    prop = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

obj = MyClass(prop='will consume', not_a_prop='will not consume')
```

kivy's property handling consumes kwargs that match the current class' kivy properties, but ONLY the ones that match, and allow the rest of them to go on to the next class in the MRO, eventually reaching `object`.

In the example above, when instantiating `MyClass`, `prop` will be consumed in `MyClass.__init__`, but since no class in the MRO has a kivy property named `not_a_prop`, it'll be passed on to the next class' `__init__` call, eventually reaching `object.__init__`